# Change character color in Assembly Fasm

Tags: assembly, fasm

I need to make the printed character green for example, but my code doesn't do this. How can I do this using BIOS Only ? (Not DOS).

```
mov ax, 9ch
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 4096d
mov ax, 7c0h
mov ds, ax
;--------------
mov ah, 0eh
mov bx, 000Ah  ;Trying to make green character color but this is not working
mov al, 'M'
int 10h
jmp $
;--------------
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

Comment: Are you sure the current display page number is 0?

Comment: I'm not sure I don't know how to check that !

Comment: The color is only used in graphics modes for `int 10/0E`.

Comment: But how to solve that !